# Detect display cutout on Android in Cordova // Ionic

Tags: android, angular, css, cordova, ionic3

is there any method, to detect the display cutout, like an Iphone has it, for and android device like a Huawei P20?

For ios, i use

```
padding: 
env(safe-area-inset-top)
env(safe-area-inset-right)
0
env(safe-area-inset-left)
```

Is there an equivalent for Android?
In an android Emulator with notch on top, these css property are marked is invalid.

Many Thanks

Comment: Try `public WindowInsets replaceSystemWindowInsets (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` for more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets#getDisplayCutout()

Comment: @Suryan How to use that in an ionic app???

Comment: If env(safe-area-inset-*) are not supported in your scenario still, this plugin may help with detection for starters:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cutout